# $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ computations for a sequence of subsets $(A_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ differing depending on $n$ odd or even

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

Define the sequence $(A_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ by
$$A_n = \begin{cases}
[0, \frac{1}{n}], & n \text{ odd} \\
[0, n], & n \text{ even}
\end{cases}\text{.}$$
Then 
$$\liminf_{n \to \infty}A_n=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\bigcap_{k \geq n}A_k = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\{0\} = \{0\}$$
and 
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty}A_n=\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{k \geq n}A_k = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}[0, \infty) = [0, \infty)\text{.}$$
Are my computations correct?

Comment: yes, they are correct